# VS2015Setup CustomAction not running

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.10

I have a separate MSI to run `devenv /setup` as part of my installation bundle, however this package always fails.

The WXS looks like this, am I missing something:

```
<Product Id="*" Name="$(var.Prep_ProductName)" Language="1033" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="fdd723a3-5072-437b-a0c4-88cca6173fc7">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade AllowDowngrades="yes" />

    <PropertyRef Id="VS2015DEVENV" />
    <CustomActionRef Id="VS2015Setup" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="VS2015Setup" Before="InstallFinalize">
        <![CDATA[VS2015DEVENV]]>
      </Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: What is the value of the VS2015DEVENV property?

Comment: How does that fail? What's the error message?

Comment: Also, please provide a logfile of your installation: "zzz.msi /lvoicewarmupx debug.log"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the bundle didn't have a componenttable, which caused a catastrophic failure in the installer. This was never going to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely failing because you cannot run recursive MSI installs. You can't have a custom action in your MSI's execute sequence that installs another MSI-based setup. That is why (for example) there are prerequisite setup.exe programs that install requirements. In this case you should do a WiX bundle and install them separately.